# How to remove '#' in url for angularjs in browser lower than ie 9 (not support html5)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, nginx, html4

Here is the situation, we created an angular app and used nginx on server side. 
We want to remove the '#' in the url even in the browsers which are not supporting html5 (like ie8, ie9).

> https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //it is not working in our situation.
```

We already tried method of the link above, which successfully remove '#' in the browsers that support html5, but in the browser like ie9, the # is still there.

We are thinking about whether we can configure nginx's file to make this happens by using mapping: http://example.com/#/abc ----->  http://example.com/abc

Because we are lack of the knowledge in nginx and we searched for the relevant questions, we still cant find any answers.

I hope someone can help and I will appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: The underlying history manipulation API is not supported by IE9 or lower. What you are asking for is simply impossible.

Comment: Can't make server do what browser doesn't support